# Redirect to a HTTPS version using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I need to modify my .htaccess file to redirect all URLs to a HTTPS version without the "www".

```
http://example.com --> https://example.com
http://www.example.com --> https://example.com
https://www.example.com --> https://example.com
```

This is how my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?id=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

What modifications do I need to make to .htaccess in order to forward to HTTPS without the "www"?

Comment: you'd have to redirect to an absolute url, e.g. `RewriteRule ... https://example.com`. if you don't use an absolute url, the browser will only redirect "locally" within the same hostname.

Comment: Indeed, and you'll need to do the redirect *before* the rewrite you already have.

Comment: I understand, but how would a redirect look like in my case?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing with your current code. That just looks like a file that is called redirect but is trying to display a php page from a SEO friendly URL. So I think that might be confusing people.

Anyway, to do what you need to do and force https without www, you only need one more rule above.

Also your second rule needs **two** capture groups in the RewriteRule test string because you are wanting two different values using $1 and $2 back references.

```
RewriteEngine On

#rediect www to non www and/or http to https --- all combinations.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ redirect.php?id=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

So this second rule will work for an URL formed like this.

```
https://example.com/123/pagename
```